# Unable to remove class before applying class again

Tags: jquery

Just want to remove highlight class before applying class again on other elements. Reseting the selected items. How?

removeClass not working in the below code.

```
$("#toggleCustom").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    $domtree = $this.parents('div.section').find('div.domtree'),
    query = $this.prev().val();
    //$domtree.removeClass('highlight').animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 'fast');
    $domtree.find(query).addClass('highlight').animate({ marginLeft: 10 }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeClass` acts only on the elements in the matched set of the jQuery instance you call it on; not on *descendants* of that set. From your code:

```
$domtree.find(query).addClass('highlight').animate({ marginLeft: 10 }, 'fast');
```

...it looks like the class is actually applied to descendant element(s) (e.g., ones matching the selector in `query`).

You can find and remove it on all descendants like this:

```
$domtree.find(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
```

Comment: ah, I get your point. let me check :). Onething. Is there any better way to write above code? . Just want to know.

Comment: @shahid: Impossible to say without more information, looks okay on first blush though.

Comment: @shahid: Glad that helped! Best,